# Silverlight на андроиде

Tags: silverlight, .net, android, c#

Может кто слышал, возможен ли запуск Silverlight на платформе андроид? Будет ли на андроиде поддержка С# и .NET? Если есть полезные ссылки по данному вопросу, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

На текущий момент (2015 год) Silverlight, судя по всему, ушёл из верхних строк приоритетов Microsoft. Официальной поддержки Android у Silverlight на текущий момент нету.

Также реимплементация от команды Mono, известная как [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/moonlight/), не планируется к дальнейшему развитию. Хотя эта платформа поддерживала Android.

Тем не менее, сама платформа .NET под Android вполне работает. Вы можете, например, использовать [UI-библиотеки Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/).

Comment: Называть Xamarin UI-библиотеками, как-то мелко

Comment: @ad1Dima: А как бы вы назвали их?

Comment: Это полноценная виртуальная .NET машина, набор обёрток для системных андроидовских библиотек, ну и кроме этого ещё дополнительно есть свой кросс-платформенный UI Framework. Так что это можно назвать технологией. А UI-библиотека, это какой-нибудь telerik

Comment: Эээ... Вы уверены, что там _действительно_ виртуальная машина? Потому что как MS .NET, так и Mono не пошли по пути виртуальной машины, а имеют нативный JIT- или AOT-компилятор.

Comment: @ad1Dima: Из их [собственного FAQ](http://xamarin.com/faq): On Android, Xamarin ships a fully functional implementation of the .NET runtime, called Mono, bundled with your app... Так что виртуальной машины нет, они используют готовую имплементацию Mono.

Comment: Mono - кросс-платформенная реализация CLR https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

Де факто, они в реальном времени выполняют промежуточный IL-код и управляют памятью.

Comment: @ad1Dima: Не совсем, промежуточный IL-код не выполняется, а компилируется в нативный код. (А в википедии написана ересь.)

Comment: Ок, называйте это так. Пусть это буден на Виртуальная машина, а JIT-компилятор с управляемой памятью, если это что-то поменяет

Answer (score 0):

Единственная надежда на Mono. Посмотрите в сторону [Mono-ARM](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM). Скорее всего, этот порт ещё очень нестабилен. Не говорю уже об интеграции в местную инфраструктуру андроида.

Если речь о чём-то серьзёном, то вам следует забыть про .NET на Android и даже не думать об этом. Не вспоминайте об этой идее по крайней мере пять лет :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы знаете C#, то перейти на Java не составит никакого труда. И дело не в самой платформе NET (хотя много классов у них с Java интуитивно схожи). Просто сам синтаксис и ООП концепция у них очень похожи (кстати Wikipedia утверждает, что C# ощутил большое влияние языка Java в своем развитии).